# Python function code modify to take round off value from user input

Tags: python

I have a code that currently looks like this, to take user input and to return to cents.
Now I want to modify my code, so it can round to the nearest 5, what kind of changes should I made?
Current code:

The example new input and output are:

input = 1.34, output =1.35

input =3.46, output =3.45

input = 123.42, output =123.40

input =123.43, output = 123.45

input 123.47, output =123.45

input 123.48, output = 123.50

Answer (score 1):

One way to implement that rounding would be:

`rounded_cents = round(cents / 5) * 5`

However, since the Python `round()` function [behaves somewhat oddly](https://realpython.com/python-rounding/) when given values of 0.5, you might replace `round()` with:

`floor(input_number + 0.5)`

Making the final line of code:

`rounded_cents = floor(cents / 5 + 0.5) * 5`

Answer (score 0):

might not be efficient, but I think this does the task

```
def myround(x, base=5):
  rem = int(str(x)[-2:])
  stem = int(str(x)[0:-3])

  #print('rem is ',rem)
  #print('stem is ',stem)  
  sol = base * round(rem/base)
  return float(str(stem)+'.'+str(sol))
  
cents = 1.48
new_cents = myround(cents)
print(new_cents)
```

UPDATE1: similar to your function

```
def adjust(cents,base = 5):
    rem = int(str(cents)[-2:])
    stem = int(str(cents)[0:-3])
    #print('rem is ',rem)
    #print('stem is ',stem)  
    converted = base * round(rem/base)
    return float(str(stem)+'.'+str(converted))
  
cents =(input("Enter a number of cents between 0 and 9: "))
# new instruction for user
#cents =(input("Enter a number with decimal place: "))
# and I will need to change this to float

print("The final round of number is: " + str(adjust(cents)))
```

**Explanation :**

You want to make sure that your number divided by 5 is an integer, correctly rounded. So, we first do exactly that (round(float(x)/5) where float is only needed in Python2), and then since we divided by 5, we multiply by 5 as well. The final conversion to int is because round() returns a floating-point value in Python 2.

I made the function more generic by giving it a base parameter, defaulting to 5.

This is a tweaked version of [this](http://It%20is%20easy%20to%20see%20why%20the%20above%20works.%20You%20want%20to%20make%20sure%20that%20your%20number%20divided%20by%205%20is%20an%20integer,%20correctly%20rounded.%20So,%20we%20first%20do%20exactly%20that%20(round(float(x)/5)%20where%20float%20is%20only%20needed%20in%20Python2),%20and%20then%20since%20we%20divided%20by%205,%20we%20multiply%20by%205%20as%20well.%20The%20final%20conversion%20to%20int%20is%20because%20round()%20returns%20a%20floating-point%20value%20in%20Python%202.%20%20I%20made%20the%20function%20more%20generic%20by%20giving%20it%20a%20base%20parameter,%20defaulting%20to%205.) answer...

Comment: that indeed work, but I don't really understand the logic behind it and it is a whole new function. would you be kind enough to explain?

Comment: sure. let me add it in the answer

Comment: added. please check